# Pandas Dataframe Stacked Bar Plot - missing y axis values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I created a stacked bar graph and would like to add a horizontal line on it but I have a problem namely the y-axis value is missing. The vertical lines work. Do you have any ideas?

```
    self.test = (
        self.test[['cat', 'x', 'y']]
        .groupby(['y','cat'])['x']
        .sum()
        .unstack('cat')
    )

    ax = self.test.plot.barh(stacked=True, legend=False)
```

it doesn't work

```
    ax.axhline(y=400, color="r")
```

Screen:

[image]

I discovered that if I change this value for example to 500 then my line is visible:

[image]

How can I set the y-axis values to the dataframe column 'y' values? Apparently there are index values set there and as label value from dateframe column 'y'

Comment: Pandas [`DataFrame.plot.barh`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html) accepts an `x` and `y` keyword argument maybe try setting one of these to `y`

Comment: it does not work